# Binding to socket failing in MacOS but not Windows VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, sockets

I'm trying to do PKCE authorization using a localhost socket to as a callback function.  It works fine in Windows, but Mac OS seems to not allow me to bind.  I've used some code published by others online to get a tcpserver going.  The code snippet in question is below.  Binding properly occurs when I use in windows, but Mac OS always returns a -1 when I get to the bind command.

Any clues as to what I have gotten wrong?  Is this a MacOS/Microsoft sandbox issue?

Thank You Ahead Of Time!

TCPServer.cls

```
Public Sub BindTo(ByVal port As Long, Optional ByVal backlog As Integer = 10)
#if Mac Then
    ' Open the socket.  Anything with wsock32.nnn comes from the 
    ' wsock32 module.  This is done to avoid redefining within the
    ' macksock module.
    m_serverSocket = macsock.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    If m_serverSocket = wsock32.INVALID_SOCKET Then
        Err.Raise StatusCode.ErrorSocketCreation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Set up the endpoint for communication    
    Dim endpoint As wsock32.sockaddr_in
    endpoint.sin_addr.s_addr = wsock32.INADDR_ANY
    endpoint.sin_family = wsock32.AF_INET   'AF_UNSPEC tried but didn't work
    endpoint.sin_port = macsock.htons(port)
    
    ' Set the socket option for reusing the address
    Dim setsockoptResult As Long
    setsockoptResult = macsock.setsockopt(m_serverSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1, 4)
    
    ' ERROR IN MAC OS HAPPENS HERE
    ' Attempt to bind.  In windows, this works fine, Mac returns a -1 no
    ' matter what options or endpoint family is set.
    Dim bindResult As Long
    bindResult = macsock.bind(m_serverSocket, endpoint, 16)
    
    If bindResult <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Last error = " & Err.LastDllError)
        Dispose
        Err.Raise StatusCode.ErrorSocketBind
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim listenResult As Long
    listenResult = macsock.listen(m_serverSocket, backlog)
    
    If listenResult <> 0 Then
        Dispose
        Err.Raise StatusCode.ErrorSocketStartListening
        Exit Sub
    End If
#Else
    '... Windows code is identical, except macsock is replaced with wsock32
#End If
End Sub
```

**macsock.bas**

```
'*******************************************************************************
' MODULE:       MacSOCK
' FILENAME:     MacSOCK.bas
' AUTHOR:       Gerhard Norkus
' CREATED:      2021-11-28
' COPYRIGHT:    Copyright 2021 Gerhard Norkus. All Rights Reserved.
'
'
'
' E-mail:    gnorkus@comcast.net
'
' MODIFICATION HISTORY:
' 2021-11-28   Gerhard Norkus     Initial Version
'*******************************************************************************

#If Mac Then

    #If VBA7 Then
    
        ' 64-bit Mac (2016)
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function socket Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal nDomain As Long, ByVal nType As Long, ByVal nProtocol As Long) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function closesocket Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "close" _
            (ByVal nSocket As Long) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function connect Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal s As Long, ByRef address As sockaddr_in, ByVal namelen As Long) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function htons Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal hostshort As Long) As Integer
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function bind Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal socket As Long, name As sockaddr_in, ByVal nameLength As Integer) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function listen Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal socket As Long, ByVal backlog As Integer) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function select_ Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal nfds As Integer, readfds As fd_set, writefds As fd_set, exceptfds As fd_set, timeout As timeval) As Integer
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function accept Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal socket As Long, clientAddress As sockaddr, clientAddressLength As Integer) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function setsockopt Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal socket As Long, ByVal level As Long, ByVal optname As Long, ByRef optval As Long, ByVal optlen As Integer) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function send Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal socket As Long, buffer As String, ByVal bufferLength As Long, ByVal flags As Long) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function recv Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal socket As Long, ByVal buffer As String, ByVal bufferLength As Long, ByVal flags As Long) As Long
        Public Declare PtrSafe Function inet_addr Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" _
            (ByVal hostname As String) As Long


    #Else
    
        ' 32-bit Mac
        Public Declare Function mac_socket Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "socket" _
            (ByVal nDomain As Integer, ByVal nType As Integer, ByVal nProtocol As Integer) As Integer
        Public Declare Function mac_close_socket Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "closesocket" _
            (ByVal nSocket As Long) As LongPtr
    
    #End If

#End If
```

**wsock32.bas**

```
Public Const WSADESCRIPTION_LEN = 256
Public Const WSASYS_STATUS_LEN = 128

Public Const WSADESCRIPTION_LEN_ARRAY = WSADESCRIPTION_LEN + 1
Public Const WSASYS_STATUS_LEN_ARRAY = WSASYS_STATUS_LEN + 1

Public Type WSADATA
    wVersion As Integer
    wHighVersion As Integer
    szDescription As String * WSADESCRIPTION_LEN_ARRAY
    szSystemStatus As String * WSASYS_STATUS_LEN_ARRAY
    iMaxSockets As Integer
    iMaxUdpDg As Integer
    lpVendorInfo As String
End Type

Public Const AF_UNSPEC As Integer = 0
Public Const AF_INET As Integer = 2
Public Const SOCK_STREAM As Integer = 1
Public Const INADDR_ANY As Integer = 0

Public Type IN_ADDR
    s_addr As Long
End Type

#If Mac Then

Public Type sockaddr_in
    sin_family As Integer
    sin_port As Integer
    sin_addr As IN_ADDR
    sin_zero As String * 8
End Type

#Else

Public Type sockaddr_in
    sin_family As Integer
    sin_port As Integer
    sin_addr As IN_ADDR
    sin_zero As String * 8
End Type

#End If

Public Const FD_SETSIZE = 64

Public Type fd_set
    fd_count As Integer
    fd_array(FD_SETSIZE) As Long
End Type

Public Type timeval
    tv_sec As Long
    tv_usec As Long
End Type

Public Type sockaddr
    sa_family As Integer
    sa_data As String * 14
End Type

Public Const INVALID_SOCKET = -1

Public Const SOL_SOCKET = 65535
Public Const SO_RCVTIMEO = &H1006

' option flags per socket
Public Const SO_DEBUG = &H1&         ' Turn on debugging info recording
Public Const SO_ACCEPTCONN = &H2&     ' Socket has had listen() - READ-ONLY.
Public Const SO_REUSEADDR = &H4&     ' Allow local address reuse.
Public Const SO_KEEPALIVE = &H8&     ' Keep connections alive.
Public Const SO_DONTROUTE = &H10&    ' Just use interface addresses.
Public Const SO_BROADCAST = &H20&    ' Permit sending of broadcast msgs.
Public Const SO_USELOOPBACK = &H40&  ' Bypass hardware when possible.
Public Const SO_LINGER = &H80&       ' Linger on close if data present.
Public Const SO_OOBINLINE = &H100&   ' Leave received OOB data in line

#If Mac Then
#Else
Public Declare PtrSafe Function WSAStartup Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal versionRequired As Long, wsa As WSADATA) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function WSAGetLastError Lib "wsock32.dll" () As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function WSACleanup Lib "wsock32.dll" () As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function socket Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal addressFamily As Long, ByVal socketType As Long, ByVal protocol As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function connect Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal s As Long, ByRef address As sockaddr_in, ByVal namelen As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function htons Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal hostshort As Long) As Integer
Public Declare PtrSafe Function bind Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, name As sockaddr_in, ByVal nameLength As Integer) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function listen Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, ByVal backlog As Integer) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function select_ Lib "wsock32.dll" Alias "select" (ByVal nfds As Integer, readfds As fd_set, writefds As fd_set, exceptfds As fd_set, timeout As timeval) As Integer
Public Declare PtrSafe Function accept Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, clientAddress As sockaddr, clientAddressLength As Integer) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function setsockopt Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, ByVal level As Long, ByVal optname As Long, ByRef optval As Long, ByVal optlen As Integer) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function send Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, buffer As String, ByVal bufferLength As Long, ByVal flags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function recv Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal socket As Long, ByVal buffer As String, ByVal bufferLength As Long, ByVal flags As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function inet_addr Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal hostname As String) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function closesocket Lib "wsock32.dll" (ByVal s As Long) As Long
#End If


Public Sub FD_ZERO_MACRO(ByRef s As fd_set)
    s.fd_count = 0
End Sub


Public Sub FD_SET_MACRO(ByVal fd As Long, ByRef s As fd_set)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    
    Do While i < s.fd_count
        If s.fd_array(i) = fd Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    If i = s.fd_count Then
        If s.fd_count < FD_SETSIZE Then
            s.fd_array(i) = fd
            s.fd_count = s.fd_count + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which port number are you trying to bind to exactly? IIRC, MacOS is more restrictive than Windows in which ports you can use. When `bind()` fails, what error code is it reporting?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I'm trying to bind to port 1992, one I picked at random so as to be less likely to conflict with others.  I haven't tried to bind to another port yet.  I'm not sure how to get the error code because I do not know which function supports the sockets error reporting.  In Windows, it's a global variable named "errno".  I'm not certain if MacOS' libc.dylib has that same reporting strategy, or if it uses something else.  If MacOS also uses errno, I don't know the syntax to access a library defined global variable in VBA as I can functions (e.g. Public Declare PtrSafe Function)

Comment: "*I'm not sure how to get the error code*" - from `errno`, or from `WSAGetLastError()` on Windows (which is really just a wrapper for `GetLastError()`, so `Err.LastDllError` *should* work). What is `macsock` defined as? Since it is wrapping the socket API functions, I would expect it to expose their error codes, too.

Comment: Err.LastDLLError reports 0

Comment: macsock is a module (just as winsock32) and it contains some functions that are identical to winsock32.  It may appear hackish, I don't know.  I was using code from other folks, and maintained their convention of calling by adding the module name and dot in front of the function call.  Do you want me to post winsock32 and macksock?

Both winsock32.bas and macsock.bas contain the external library declarations to use either wsock32.dll (windows) or libc.dylib (macos).  There are some global constant definitions in wsock32 that I chose not to repeat in macsock.

Comment: "*Do you want me to post winsock32 and macksock?*" - if it is anything like [this module](https://github.com/michaelneu/webxcel/blob/master/src/Modules/wsock32.bas), then have you looked to see if it has defined a `WSAGetLastError()` function (or equivalent)?

Comment: WSAGetLastError is only on Windows systems.  It's not part of MacOS or Linux versions of sockets.  I was a little stumped to see I had no way of knowing what the error was.  I did a search to see if anyone using Mac VBA had an example of socket error reporting, but came up blank.

Comment: Your `macsock.bas` is just importing functions from `libc.dylib`. `errno` is a thread-local variable, so check if `libc.dylib` is exporting any `errno`-related function to access it. Otherwise, check if it is exporting `perror()`, at least.

Comment: Thx, I declared perror as follows:

Public Declare PtrSafe Function perror Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" () As Long

Not sure if that's the correct length, perhaps it should be only 16 bits?  In any case, the return value is as follows:

577,568,931 (decimal)
226D 00A3 (hexadecimal)

Even if I trim off the upper 16 bits, not sure that A3 is anything understandable?  I'll check around...

Comment: I changed the declaration of perror after I found documentation on it.  perror outputs a string to a pointer that is provided as input.  Public Declare PtrSafe Function perror Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" (ByRef tstr as String).  It gives a blank value as the result when I run the bind function.  According the the Unix man pages, errno should allow perror to generate a text description of the error.  No paydirt yet....  (thx for the help)

Comment: "*perror outputs a string to a pointer that is provided as input*" - no, it doesn't. [`perror()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) outputs to the calling process's `stderr`. It outputs the input string if not empty, followed by the error message, followed by a line break.  If you want the error message written to a string buffer, use [`strerror()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I noted what you said just before your reply.  problem with strerror is it requires the index of the error, essentially errno.  It's a Catch-22.  Thanks too for your patience...